# What is the value of uncertainty of $\exp(x)$, if $x$ has the value $x=4.005(0.068)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

Simply, I have a physical quantity that is described by a value of $$x=4.005\,(0.068),$$ where the value in braces is the standard uncertainty of its value. How can I compute value of $\exp(x)$ and find the standard uncertainty of this quantity?

It has been a real conundrum for me for a while.

Comment: There are several options; one is the functional approach. It would just be that the uncertainty is $|\exp(x + \delta x) - \exp(x)|$.

Comment: @JamalS what about complex uncertainty formulae ? I have a function which is differentiable (exp), and uncertainty of argument is given .

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach, as suggested in the comments is the functional one. Roughly speaking, you have a differentiable function $f(x)$ and you know that the uncertainty on your variable (at a fixed value) is $\delta_x$.

One can prove that the value of the uncertainty on $f$ is given by

$$\delta_f = \vert\partial_x f\vert \delta_x$$

In case you have a function of more than one variable $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and uncertainties $\delta_{x_1},\ldots, \delta_{x_n}$ the uncertainty on $f$ can be calculated by
$$\delta_f = \sqrt{(\partial_{x_1} f \delta_{x_1})^2 + \ldots +(\partial_{x_n} f \delta_{x_n})^2 }$$

Comment: Note: one should say that the last formula holds only when the variables have no correlation between them.

Comment: This is not the functional approach FYI; the wording at the start makes it sound like it is.